# How can I get the drop down menu to show? User Registration Form

Tags: php, html, registration

I'm working through some legacy code from a previous developer and I'm very new to php. Here is my challenge, the registration form works as is.

The problem is the drop down menu that allows a user to self select their usertype does not appear on the form/page. I need it to.

Currently this bit of code stores all new users in the db as user1.

How can I get the drop down to show? And alter it from auto saving as user1?

index.html.php

```
<body id="page-login" onload="document.registerForm.name.focus();">
'. getMsg() .'
<div class="login-container">
<div class="logo_login"><img src="'. $mainframe->cfg->site_url .'/images/logo.gif"></div>
    <div class="login-box">
        <form method="post" action="" name="registerForm" id="registerForm" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="login-form">
                <h2>'. LANG::_('register') .'</h2>
                <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="name">'. LANG::_('name') .':</label><br/>
                            <input type="text"  class="txt" id="name" name="name" value="" class="required-entry input-text" style="width:130px;"/>
                        </div>
                <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="link">'. LANG::_('Add your profile link') .':</label><br/>
                            <input type="text"  class="txt" id="link" name="link" value="" class="required-entry input-text" style="width:130px;"/>
                        </div>

                <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="username">'. LANG::_('user_name') .':</label><br/>
                            <input type="text"  class="txt" id="username" name="username" value="" class="required-entry input-text" style="width:130px;"/>
                        </div>

                <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="email">'. LANG::_('email_address') .':</label><br/>
                            <input type="text" class="txt" id="email" name="email" value="" class="required-entry input-text" style="width:130px;"/>
                        </div>

                <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="password">'. LANG::_('password') .':</label><br />
                            <input type="password" class="txt" id="password" name="password" class="required-entry input-text" value="" style="width:130px;"/>
                        </div>



                '. ($mainframe->cfg->allow_only_coach_or_player ? '<div class="input-box input-left"><label for="usertype">'. LANG::_('register_me_as') .':</label><br />
                    <select name="usertype" class="required-entry select">
                        <option value="">--'. LANG::_('choose_one') .'--</option>
                        <option value="Coach">'. LANG::_('contest_holder') .'</option>
                        <option value="Player">'. LANG::_('contest_participant') .'</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>' 
                    : '<input name="usertype"  value="user1" />') .'

                <div class="input-box input-left"><label for="password2">'. LANG::_('r_password') .':</label><br />
                            <input type="password"  class="txt" id="password2" name="password2" class="required-entry input-text" value="" style="width:130px;"/>
                        </div>`
```

Comment: `$mainframe->cfg->allow_only_coach_or_player` <- find out what that configuration variable is set to; looks as though it's evaluating as falsey.

Comment: I do not see any HTML that is responsible for a dropdown menu on this page. That must mean that the code for the dropdown menu must be in another PHP file located somewhere else that is responsible for this `$mainframe->cfg->allow_only_coach_or_player` I'd say is a good start.

Comment: @robotsushi the drop down menu is the <select> and <option> tags. it's in there

Comment: @robotsushi - the HTML select **is** in the code, it's not being pulled in from another file **all** that `$mainframe->cfg->allow_only_coach_or_player` is being used as is a boolean to determine whether to display the `<select>` box or not. There's probably a config file somewhere, containing that `cfg` object with a member called `allow_only_coach_or_player` set to `false`.

Comment: OHHHHHH yeah I see it.